# “Sorry, This File Type Is Not Permitted for Security Reasons” when uploading images using Woocommerce REST API "automattic/woocommerce"

Tags: laravel, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce REST API package "automattic/woocommerce" along with laravel, while im trying to create a product with images i'm getting “Sorry, This File Type Is Not Permitted for Security Reasons” although the files are .jpeg. How can i fix this in case of using this package.

Comment: Did you check with jpg & png files, is it working?

Comment: yes it is working just fine, for some images, and not for some even though they are also jpeg.

Comment: it seem might be an issue with image encoding, you need to allow new file types into WordPress and then test again.